# display flex inside li element hides numbering

Tags: html, css, list, flexbox

I need to use display: flex for a li element in an ordered list. The problem is the flex will
hide the list numbering. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/pzpeam7o/

I am using spans inside the li element. The flex allows better behavior when resizing the page.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head lang="en">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="lst"> First item</li>
        <li class="lst"> Second item</li>
        <li class="lst"> Third item</li>
        <li class="lst"> Fourth item</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

CSS :

```
.lst {
    list-style-type: decimal;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind mentioning why exactly you *need* display flex?

Comment: @LcSalazar: that was going to be exactly my question.

Comment: I am using spans inside the li element. The flex allows better behavior when resizing the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for starters you have the [flex model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) concept wrong. The `display:flex` goes not on the items but on the container block, so in your case, it should be in the `<UL>`, like this:

```
ul {
    display: flex;
}
.lst {
    list-style-type: decimal;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Now, if you check [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2puoxoh/), you'll see your numbers there. The bad news: there's a [documented bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4522) in Mozilla and doesn't work with Firefox, it only shows 0.

So, with all this being said, I'd suggest to ditch the Flex model in this case, or change your approach (why not use divs with a counter?) because you're looking for trouble and cross browser issues not worthy of whatever solution they could provide

**EDIT:** Now I see [LcSalazar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25942579/1165565) answer and he also suggests counters although with another approach, so I think you could try playing with my answer plus LcSalazar's counter's and get a cross browser result while still using full flex model. It might work.

Answer (score 8):

I have absolutely no idea why it hides it... but...

A solution might be mocking the decimal list with a [**CSS Counter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters), placed with a `:before` pseudo on the list item. This way you have the `display: flex`, and your numbers are still there...

Even better, if you want to style only the numbers differently, you can!!

```css
body {
    counter-reset: section;
}

.lst {
 display: flex;
}

.lst:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: counter(section) ".";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="lst"> First item</li>
    <li class="lst"> Second item</li>
    <li class="lst"> Third item</li>
    <li class="lst"> Fourth item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think you'll need to add list-style-type:none for Safari, but nice idea nevertheless, +1 for you. 1 thing though: As I mentioned in my answer, display flex goes in the ul, not the li

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot.